# ansible connection establishment to windows machine

Tags: windows, ansible

I am a basic learner to ansible and trying to establish the connection to windows machine and observing below error

> "msg": "ssl: auth method ssl requires a username",

and i have gone through multiple sections in github but they are not working
can you please help me in fixing the below
i have executed the below powershell script but it didn't give any error
I know this error is related to this [line of code](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/blob/master/winrm/transport.py) 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638896/ssl-auth-method-ssl-requires-a-password) is the forum who suggested it is code level change
but didn't understand where this to be added i didn't find this file. I have installed **python2-winrm-0.3.0-1.el7.noarch**

Help me in sorting out this issue

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] not relying on external resources.

Comment: do you want what exactly i have done or what  ? for an Issue how can i give you a example

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask]. See `If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS.`.

Answer (score -2):

For connecting ansible to Windows machine you need to do some pre-requisite.

You need to run a ansible powershell script. The instructions is easily available on the ansible documentation